# Delete a user by email in lieu of UID Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am successfully deleting accounts with an account UID in a Firebase Function, but is it possible to delete an authenticated account via an email address vs. their UID?

This is what I have now:

```
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(userEmail).then(function(userRecord) {
            // See the UserRecord reference doc for the conteenter code herents of userRecord.
            console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
        
            admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord)
            
              .then(function

() {
            console.log('This is the ID being used!', userRecord);
    
            console.log('Successfully deleted user');
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('This is the ID being used!', userRecord);
    
            console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
          });
    
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
       console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
      });
    
    
        });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The admin sdk don't have a method to delete by user so It's not posible to delete user with email. You could use the way that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [deleteUser(uid)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#deleteuser) to delete the user account as a second operation after you find the account with [getUserByEmail()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getuserbyemail).  The [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord) it returns has a [uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#uid) field in it.

So, instead of what you're doing now:

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord)
```

Do this instead:

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid)
```